# What kind of message can be transported through ActiveMQ?

Tags: c#, c++, activemq-classic

We are building a distributed system, maybe a c# app will talk to a c++ app, and maybe some jpeg image will ben send between, is this possible with Activemq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can transport any XML message, and also binary messages (blob messages, see http://activemq.apache.org/blob-messages.html). Since ActiveMQ won't try to interpret the binary message, you can safely send JPEGs or other stuff around.